# Reading a value from Entity B when reading Entity A (left join on non PK column) - JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

so I have:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

  @EmbeddedId
  private MyId id;

  // not a part of Entity but a part of OtherEntity
  private String lookedUpValue;

}

public class MyId {
   private String firstField;
   private String secondField;
}
```

Table looks like:

```
ENTITY
  FIRSTFIELD (PK)
  SECONDFIELD (PK)
  // etc.

public class OtherEntity {
  private String firstField;
  private String value;
}
```

Table looks like:

```
OTHERENTITY
  VALUE (PK)
  FIRSTFIELD 
  //etc.
}
```

When I read Entity I want there to be a LEFT JOIN to populate its lookedUpValue field where `Entity.id.firstField = OtherEntity.firstField` i.e. in SQL it would be:

```
Select ENTITY.FIRSTFIELD, ENTITY.SECONDFIELD, OTHERENTITY.VALUE 
from ENTITY
left join OTHERENTITY
ON ENTITY.FIRSTFIELD = OTHERENTITY.FIRSTFIELD
```

So Entity instances would get populated with all these fields.

Is this possible, or do you recommend another approach?  Reading OtherEntity as a field on each Entity could work too - but because MyId does not map to OtherEntity I do not see how to achive that.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A way to reference the OtherEntity in Entity using the JoinColumn annotation, the below code to be in Entity.

```
@OneToOne(optional="true")
@JoinColumn(name="FIRSTFIELD",referencedColumnName="FIRSTFIELD")
OtherEntity otherEntity;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [JPQL Constructor Expressions](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_constructor) here.

Basically, you create a DTO with all the fields you need and use it's constructor (with `NEW`) in the query.